# Whether Selenium Grid has public API documentation available?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm looking for API documentation for Selenium Grid v3 (v.3.141.59). It's available anywhere? The best way will be some Swagger like docs or at least some more actual third party documentation?

I'm building tool where I need to dynamically scale Hub nodes (add and subtract) them during tests execution.

Thanks in advance,
Marcin

Comment: For swagger like documentation .I have not seen any you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983811/api-for-getting-the-selenium-nodes-status-from-the-grid-host for start. You can also check https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid if you wish to use docker containers

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/aerokube/selenium-openapi) is our recent effort to document [Selenium Webdriver protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/) with [OpenAPI 3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) (aka Swagger) YAML spec. Note that this standard (and thus our spec) does not cover some Selenium Grid specific methods like `/grid/register`.

Comment: Btw, regarding scaling the cluster we provide our own Selenium-compatible solutions. Take a look at articles referred at the bottom of our web site: https://aerokube.com/